# Easier way to have production, qualif and dev settings in same file

Tags: python, import, settings

To have in the same file all settings I have proceed as follow:

-settings.py

```
def dev():
  SUPER_TOKEN = "devdevdevdvdevdev"
  CLIENT_ID = "devdevdevdvdevdev"
  CLIENT_SECRET = "devdevdevdvdevdev"
  return locals()

def prod():
  SUPER_TOKEN = "prodprodprodprodprod"
  CLIENT_ID = "prodprodprodprod"
  CLIENT_SECRET = "prodprodprodprod"
  return locals()

def qualif():
  SUPER_TOKEN = "qualifqualifqualifqualifqualifqualif"
  CLIENT_ID = "qualifqualifqualifqualifqualifqualif"
  CLIENT_SECRET = "qualifqualifqualifqualifqualifqualif"
  return locals()

ENV = qualif
#assert ENV in (dev, prod, qualif)
globals().update(ENV())
```

I wonder myself if I can do it in an another way ?

Comment: Why not using [config](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#module-ConfigParser) files?

Comment: I wonder why, as production settings are usually too sensitive to be shared among dev (at least for data security and robustness), and dev settings may vary among many dev instances/landscape configurations.

Comment: In my snipet, the ENV variable is set in the file but, it Could be set via ENV variable. Using config could be a good choice but I will have to change all my code (legacy code). It's a script that a run only on my PC :)